# Populating select shows 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to populate a select from some data but it keep giving me undefined. The actual code works fine, I'm thinking its the format that's the problem?

Here's the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurlhere',
    method: 'GET',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(result, value) {
            $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value.id).attr('value', value.id));
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the Data:

```
{
    "cars":[{
        "id":"654",
        "type": "ford"
    },{
        "id":"650",
        "type": "fiat"
    }]
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to loop through `result.cars`, not `result`:

```
$.each(result.cars, function(i, value) {
    $('#myselect').append($('<option>', {
        text: value.id,
        value: value.id
    }));
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/eaqdhLm3/)

Also note that it's incredibly bad practice to use`async: false` - if you check the browser you'll see warnings about its use. You should remove it.